# mySQL - Adding multiple Item ids from inventory table to order table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im working on a project to learn database and client design and I'm a bit stuck. My order table consists of:

```
- order_id(int(11)) - This is the primary key and is auto incrementing.
- customer_id(int(11)) - A foreign key to the customer table 
- bike_id(int(11)) - A foreign key to the bikes table 
- equipment_id(int(11)) - A foreign key to the equipment table.
- date_from(datetime)  
- date_to(datetime)
```

What im trying to do is allowing a customer to have multiple bike_ids inside the order_id separated by a comma like so "6, 8, 10" - same goes for equipment_ids

I suspect it might be the datatype for bike_id which is an int and that it does not allow anything other than a single whole number.

Im starting to feel like this might be poor database design, but I dont see any other way of doing this at the moment. This is also going to be one of the main features of the system - so I want to get it right. I have no problem reading documentation, so perhaps someone can give me some pointers to how this kind of problem should be solved?

Comment: dont store data `comma separated` instead insert a separate row for single `id`

Comment: If i understand you correctly i would then structure it like so: order_id, customer_id, bike_id, bike_id, bike_id ... ?

Comment: No, in rows, not in columns. Read about normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Yngve Molnes* asked in comment I will explain for you.

Store data data comma separated is bad practice. You should store `bike_id` like that:

```
order_id customer_id bike_id equipment_id date_from date_to
   1          1         1         1         2015      2016
   1          1         2         1         2015      2016
   1          1         3         1         2015      2016
   2          1         7         1         2014      2015
   2          1         4         1         2014      2015
```

You can read [documentation](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) about database normalization.

---

> Comma-separated lists have a lot practical problems:

- Can’t ensure that each value is the right data type: no way to
  prevent 1,2,3,banana,5
- Can’t use foreign key constraints to link values to a lookup table;
  no way to enforce referential integrity.
- Can’t enforce uniqueness: no way to prevent 1,2,3,3,3,5
- Can’t delete a value from the list without fetching the whole list.
- Can't store a list longer than what fits in the string column.
- Hard to search for all entities with a given value in the list; you
  have to use an inefficient table-scan. May have to resort to regular
  expressions, for example in MySQL: idlist REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]'
- Hard to count elements in the list, or do other aggregate queries.
- Hard to join the values to the lookup table they reference.
- Hard to fetch the list in sorted order.
- Storing integers as strings takes about twice as much space as
  storing binary integers. Not to mention the space taken by the comma
  characters.

More about [Comma-Separated lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: I accepted this as an answer, because it got me on the right track. Thank you for being so informative!